# Create dirs with capistrano after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, bash, capistrano

I have deploy.rb file with this pice of code:

```
after :deploy do
  run "if [ -d #{rails_root}/tmp/pids ]; then mkdir #{rails_root}/tmp/pids && chmod 0777 #{rails_root}/tmp/pids; fi"
end
```

There are trouble, you can see it @ screenshot of terminal:
[image]

The same troube is with log dir, but it's just cloned from git repo (via capistrano). When I clone project manualy - the log dir works well.
[image]

Two questions:

1. What is pids/log "dir", if it isn't file or dir or something else?
2. How can I solve this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of suggestions:

`man test` shows

```
-d file       True if file exists and is a directory.
```

so you probably mean if [ ! -d xxx/tmp/pids ];

for easier tryout, just run the shell command in a temp directory:

```
if [ ! -d xxx/tmp/pids ]; then mkdir xxx/tmp/pids && chmod 0777 xxx/tmp/pids; fi
```

mkdir fails if dirs further up the path don't exists - use mkdir -p

```
if [ ! -d xxx/tmp/pids ]; then mkdir -p xxx/tmp/pids && chmod 0777 xxx/tmp/pids; fi
```

that should do what you intended.

(the screenshots are quite hard to decipher. if you want to get more information on a file type, use `ls -l` and rather copy the text output here than a screenshot showing mainly your background image...)